# Unable to connect to EC2 Ubuntu instance from Putty

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, putty

Im getting the error : Putty Fatal Error.  Network Error: Connection Refused.

[image]

Security Group SSH rule:

[image]

I was able to connect to the instance a few hours ago. I did not change anything. What am I missing? Please help.

Instance is running :

[image]

**Putty configuration:**

[image]

[image]

System Log:

[image]

Btw, i am able to RDP to the instance by following https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/

Comment: What does the system log say? (Right-click an instance, instance settings, system log)

Comment: added the system log screenshot. and Im able to RDP from my Windows 10. I followed : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/ Does this has got to do something with the Putty error?

Comment: try ip instead of host name. Also, what AMI you've used to create the instance? Click on AMI ID in the instance description.

Comment: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20170330 (ami-83a8dbec) this is the ami id .. did not work with the ip address also :(

Comment: Can you connect from inside the VPC?

Comment: How to connect to it from VPC? @Exelian